# Differenza di significato fra questi verbi?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, difference, synonym

Dare, conferire, assegnare, attribuire.

Il dizionario li dà come sinonimi, anche se alcune frasi mi suonano un po' male:

1. Ti ho dato un incarico.
2. Ti ho dato dei soldi.
3. Ti ho dato la colpa.
4. Ti ho dato un premio.

Il verbo dare in sé regge qualsiasi sostantivo, mentre gli altri verbi da me elencati mi risultano a volte inadatti.

Esempio:

- Ti ho conferito/assegnato  la colpa.
- Ti ho conferito/assegnato dei soldi.

La mia sensazione era inizialmente che i verbi elencati, ad eccezione di "dare", potessero sostituirsi a quest'ultimo sono nei casi di sostantivi che indicano qualcosa di astratto (colpa o incarico) e non fisico (premio o soldi).
Sinceramente andrei per intuito, ma mi trovo in difficoltà nell'uso di questi verbi.
Potete aiutarmi?

Comment: Quale dizionario hai consultato? Attenzione, in ogni caso: quando si propongono dei sinonimi non significa che siano sempre intercambiabili con la parola di partenza: sono delle indicazioni che poi vanno approfondite in base alla propria conoscenza della lingua o a un'ulteriore consultazione dei dizionari.

Comment: Hai provato a consultare qualche dizionario per chiarirti meglio le sfumature dei quattro verbi che ti interessano?

Comment: @DaG: sì, ma continuo a non vederci chiaro. Potresti darmi qualche consiglio sul corretto uso dei verbi citati?

Answer (score 5):

Attenzione, il fatto che due verbi siano sinonimi non gli conferisce lo stesso identico significato, né segnala che siano sempre e in ogni contesto intercambiabili; consiglio quindi di valutare in ogni contesto il verbo da usare dopo aver capito le varie sfumature di significato.

**Attribuire**: assegnare con giudizio, ritenere originato da. Esempi: La commissione ha attribuito il premio a ... / La morte di... è attribuita all'eccessivo uso di farmaci.

**Assegnare**: fissare come proprio, stabilire, affidare. Esempio: Lo stato ha assegnato ai militari le terre conquistate.

**Conferire**:  aggiungere, concedere. Esempio: La spezia conferisce sapore al piatto.

Attenzione: questi sono i significati molto riassunti; ti consiglio di cercare i verbi nel sito della Treccani per ulteriori dettagli.

Comment: Mi sono permesso di ritoccare qualcosa: forse ti era scappato qualche refuso al telefonino. (E, occhio: “è attribuita _all'_uso”, non “dall'uso”.)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!